# summing number of different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I want to return the list of data frames with the number of different columns apart from the name column, which I want to return the same. So for this example, it would return

```
list3$dfa

     names X  Y   Z
1    Ben   1  1   2

list3$dfb

   names  X  Y  Z
1  John   2  2  2
```

Kindly let me know how I would do this, please.

Comment: Why did you remove data from your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` :

```
Map(function(x, y) data.frame(Name = x[[1]][1], 
                       t(colMeans(x[-1] != y[-1])) * 100), list1, list2)

#$dfa
#  Name    X    Y    Z
#1  Ben 33.3 33.3 66.7

#$dfb
#  Name  X  Y  Z
#1 John 50 50 75
```

Comment: @user123231322 Does it give you numbers instead of characters? Is your `names` column factor? You can add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your dataframe call to change it to character? Is `names` 1st column in your list of dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2(list1, list2, ~  
      tibble(Name = select(.x, names) %>% slice(1),
      map2_dfc(.x[-1], .y[-1],  ~ 100 *mean(.x != .y))))
#$dfa
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  Name$names     X     Y     Z
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Ben         33.3  33.3  66.7

#$dfb
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  Name$names     X     Y     Z
#  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 John          50    50    75
```